# On hovering first child component is extending downward while other component are extending upward

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!-- .our-service-section -->
        <section class="our-service-section" style="background-image: url('assets/img/our-service-bg.png');">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="section-title text-center">
                  Our Services
                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="container-fluid service-box-container">
                <div class="service-box-item">
                    <div class="sbi-title">
                        <h3>Panel Repair</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sbi-description">
                        <p>
                          We specialise in vehicle accident repairs, collision repairs and vehicle
                          spray painting.
                        </p>
                        <div class="read-more-link">
                          <a href="#" class="ks-btn ks-btn-light">
                            <span class="arrow-dark">Learn More</span>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="service-box-item">
                  <div class="sbi-title">
                    <h3>Service Title</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sbi-description">
                    <p>
                      We specialise in vehicle accident repairs, collision repairs and vehicle
                      spray painting.
                    </p>
                    <div class="read-more-link">
                      <a href="#" class="ks-btn ks-btn-light">
                        <span class="arrow-dark">Learn More</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="service-box-item">
                  <div class="sbi-title">
                    <h3>Service Title</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sbi-description">
                    <p>
                      We specialise in vehicle accident repairs, collision repairs and vehicle
                      spray painting.
                    </p>
                    <div class="read-more-link">
                      <a href="#" class="ks-btn ks-btn-light">
                        <span class="arrow-dark">Learn More</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="service-box-item">
                  <div class="sbi-title">
                    <h3>Service Title</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sbi-description">
                    <p>
                      We specialise in vehicle accident repairs, collision repairs and vehicle
                      spray painting.
                    </p>
                    <div class="read-more-link">
                      <a href="#" class="ks-btn ks-btn-light">
                        <span class="arrow-dark">Learn More</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="service-box-item">
                  <div class="sbi-title">
                    <h3>Service Title</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sbi-description">
                    <p>
                      We specialise in vehicle accident repairs, collision repairs and vehicle
                      spray painting.
                    </p>
                    <div class="read-more-link">
                      <a href="#" class="ks-btn ks-btn-light">
                        <span class="arrow-dark">Learn More</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- /.our-service-section -->
```

And, here is my CSS:

```
/**********************
   OUR SERVICE SECTION
***********************/
.our-service-section .main-container{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.service-box-item{
    border-top: 1px solid #5C5D62;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.service-box-item .sbi-title h3{
    line-height: 36px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.service-box-item .sbi-description{
    display: none;
}
.service-box-item .sbi-description p{
    line-height: 24px;
}
.sbi-description .read-more-link{
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.service-box-item:hover{
    justify-content: center;
}
.service-box-item:hover .sbi-description{
    display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .service-box-container{
        border-top: 5px solid #5C5D62;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .service-box-item{
        display: flex;
        padding: 60px 30px;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-basis: 20%;
    }
    .service-box-item:not(:first-child){
        border-left: 1px solid #5C5D62;
    }
}
```

To make it show exactly how it looks I am also sharing this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/f3ct4pyv/)

**Here, please note that, you must be looking in screen width greater or equal to 992px**

When I hover on `service-box-item` second child or any other child except first one, it is extending upward, (there will be no shift in screen viewing point).

[image]

But if I hover,over first child, it is extending toward downside, which looks weird, how could I fix it?

[image]

This is what actually looks while hovering.

[image]

Comment: You've described the behaviour you get but not want you want to achieve. Do you want them to all move upwards? All downwards? Or to not move at all? The movement is because you have a `display:none` which removes the space occupied by the element, the space is put back when you change to `display: inline-block`.  To stop any movement, set `display:inline-block` and change the hover `display:none` to `visibility:hidden` (which reserves the space even when nothing is showing).

Comment: On that case, I want to behave like same, if all 4 are going upward, I want that with first too. More than anything else, I want all of them to be consistent with one another.

Comment: By the way, when it is not hovered, I want that title to be shown on bottom positions.

Comment: as I said, replace `display:none` with `display:hidden` to stop the movement. Your title shows above the description because that's how you've ordered the html `div`s, change the order if you want the title at the bottom.  Lastly, remove `.service-box-item:hover` css and put `justify-content: center;` inside the `.service-box-item` block. I can't write a codepen for you because your code is too cumbersome, a [Minimal, Reproducible Example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#comment-formatting) would have helped you attract answers.